# React js .bind(this) in hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I want to transform this code [My code in link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-server-side-data-rjyji?file=/index.js:1978-2026), so that it works with hooks, what I can not do is to transform `this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);` which is done in the `constructor` using hooks, and how to get the state

```
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  data: [],
  pages: null,
  loading: true,
  sorted: []
};
this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);}


fetchData(state, instance) {
// Whenever the table model changes, or the user sorts or changes pages, this method gets called and passed the current table model.
// You can set the `loading` prop of the table to true to use the built-in one or show you're own loading bar if you want.
this.setState({ loading: true });
// Request the data however you want.  Here, we'll use our mocked service we created earlier
requestData(state.pageSize, state.page, state.sorted, state.filtered).then(
  res => {
    // Now just get the rows of data to your React Table (and update anything else like total pages or loading)
    this.setState({
      data: res.rows,
      pages: res.pages,
      loading: false
    });
  }
);
```

}

Comment: You want to rewrite the **App** component using only Hooks?

Answer (score 1):

From the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html): *You can’t use Hooks inside a class component.*

You need to **convert your component to a functional component**.

When you have done that, there is no `this`, and you don't have to do any `this.bind`s to get things working.

Then for storing and accessing state, use a series of [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hooks.